# How to retain part of a string when using SED?

Tags: vim, replace

I have multiple lines in a file like these

```
APPLE JUICE
APPLE JAM
APPLE JELLY
```

I want to replace "APPLE" with "ORANGE" and append "SHOP" to the end of the string. The output would be

```
ORANGE JUICE SHOP
ORANGE JAM SHOP
ORANGE JELLY SHOP
```

How to do this in sed or vim?

EDIT1:
I found a solution that works in sed

```
#replace APPLE with ORANGE 
sed -i s/APPLE/ORANGE/g foo.txt
#in a line containing ORANGE replace newline with SHOP
sed -i '/ORANGE/s/$/ SHOP/g'
```

the problem now is that I can't get the second command to work in vim. So this is a vim question now.

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty basic... You'll need the `s` command to substitute text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
kent$  echo "APPLE JUICE
APPLE JAM
APPLE JELLY"|sed 's/\bAPPLE\b/ORANGE/;s/$/ SHOP/'
ORANGE JUICE SHOP
ORANGE JAM SHOP
ORANGE JELLY SHOP
```

I added word boundary, so that something like `PINEAPPLE` won't be replaced by `PINEORANGE`

in vim, with the same idea:

```
%s/\<APPLE\>/ORANGE/|%s/$/ SHOP/
```

**EDIT**

when I posted the answer, there is no requirement that, appending `SHOP` only if there is an ORANGE match.  OP updated the question after my answer.

anyway, I added another vim cmd:

```
%s/\<APPLE\>/ORANGE/g|%s/.*\<ORANGE\>.*/& SHOP/
```

Comment: Awesome that you answered, but we should encourage users to try something on their own and then come here with problems, rather than have them ask without trying. (I'm sure this is a heavily discussed topic here/meta, just my 2¢)

Comment: Thank you! The vim solution is what i needed. Thanks again!

Comment: @Siddhartha What he suppose to do, add another comment "what have you tried?".

Answer (score 2):

No, @Kent's answer elide rows not containing APPLE and append SHOP to all lines in file. You need to use RE sub-expressions:

```
echo "APPLE JUICE\
CHERRY JAM\
APPLE JELLY" | sed 's/^APPLE \(.*\)$/ORANGE \1 SHOP/'
ORANGE JUICE SHOP
CHERRY JAM
ORANGE JELLY SHOP
```

Comment: when I answered the question, there is no requirement that appending the SHOP only if there was an `APPLE`. also the new requirement is, appending SHOP for ORANGE. :)

Answer (score 2):

In vim itself try this one in command mode

:%s/APPLE \ (.*\ )/ORANGE \1 SHOP/g

Comment: If an original line has `ORANGE` but without `APPLE`, this command won't add `SHOP` to that line. `#in a line containing ORANGE replace newline with SHOP`

Answer (score 0):

@dyomas is right that @Kent's answer indiscriminately appends `SHOP` to *all* lines.

Here is a solution that **does not use sub-expressions**; instead, it uses the `t` command that tests for substitutions and only then appends `SHOP`.

```
sed 's/\bAPPLE\b/ORANGE/; t append; b; :append s/$/ SHOP/'
```

Because the `t` command jumps in case of substitution (but we need the opposite), we have to jump "over" a `b` command that otherwise aborts the line processing.